# I want to share my internet connection with my portable devices

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, internet, proxy, connection-sharing

Greetings.

I'm currently deployed to Iraq with the military. *I want to share the internet connection I have (which is ethernet) with all of my portable devices using WiFi.*

The internet situation here is pretty abysmal. $110/month for 256kbps!! Yes that is **Kilobits**. Each machine on the network must authenticate via a login webpage that pops up when you first connect.

I've tried using the Mac internet connection sharing, and/or using a wireless access point. The ISP's authentication seems to use RADIUS and each session seems to be authenticated by IP and MAC address. Thus I can't share the connection like this.

I've read about using [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and have installed [SquidMan](http://web.me.com/adg/squidman/index.html) but don't fully understand how to configure it.

***Bottom Line*: I need a tutorial on sharing my internet connection via wifi.**

Comment: Ad-Hoc Network?

Comment: What goes wrong when you use internet connection sharing?  With that, all connections from "behind" the Mac should look like they're coming from its IP and ethernet MAC address, so I'd expect them to look just like connections from the Mac itself.  Unless they're using something like a browser cookie ... if you run two browsers, does each one have to log in separately?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you setup Squid, your shared devices will only be able to browse the web -- so an iPhone hooked up to the shared connection will not be able to send or receive e-mail, for example.

Did you try the Mac's built-in connection sharing? It uses NAT, so unless your ISP is doing some sophisticated traffic monitoring, they should have no idea that you have multiple devices sharing a single connection.

Here's a quick example. Go into System Preferences and click Sharing. Then select Internet Sharing from the list on the left. On the right side, go to "From" and select Ethernet, and 
under "To" select airport.

Then I recommend you click on Airport Options and set up some security for your wifi network. They only let you use WEP (bad) but better than nothing if you think other people nearby might try to latch onto your shared connection without asking. Notice the "password" should be exactly five characters and only use numbers 0-9 and/or letters A-F. Other letters and punctuation won't work.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) would be a possibility?

Comment: Not even related to the issue at hand...

Comment: ? It is a proxy service that you could run on the Mac and have the other devices connect through, and it is simpler to setup that squid (or was last time I tried squid).

Answer (score 0):

if they are using a Radius server for Auth. then likely they are using PPPoE to get the connection running. I remember when I had gotten a dsl at one of my apparments and I was having the same issue getting a router to work.  after some investigation into what was going on behind the scenes I discovered the log in page I was getting was from the dsl modem, when the connection timed out it would send me a page asking me to log in, then the modem would go use the info I gave it to restart the ppoe link.  what I ended up doing is finding instructions online as to how to set the modem from it's default router mode into full on bridge mode, then I plugged in the router set it to use pppoe and put in my user/pass and then finally the router had a valid wan ip and I could surf with my computer connected to the router. and could then join other computers to the the routers wi-fi and get everything working.  though I noticed if I connected bouth my computer and my router directly to the modem then it was either get that one computer working or get everything connected behind the router working. so made sure to not plug anything other then the router in and it worked like charm from then on.